# caretEnsmble with different trained datasets with SVM (issue)

Tags: svm, r-caret, ensemble-learning

The following is a reproducible example, what basically I am trying to do, is creating five imputed dataset then apply SVM to each imputed dataset using the train function in caret, then ensemble the resulted training model using caretEnsemble. Lastly, I am predicting each test set using the ensemble model.

However, I get this error

> Error in check_bestpreds_obs(modelLibrary) :
>   Observed values for each component model are not the same.  Please re-train the models with the same Y variable

Is there anyway around that can help me ensemble different training models ?

Any help is truly appreciated.

```
    library(mice)
    library(e1071)
    library(caret)
    library("caretEnsemble")

data <- iris
#Generate 10% missing values at Random 
iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.1)
#remove categorical variables
iris.mis <- subset(iris.mis, select = -c(Species))

# 5 Imputation using mice pmm

imp <- mice(iris.mis, m=5, maxit = 10, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)

# save 5 imputed dataset.
x1 <- complete(imp, action = 1, include = FALSE)
x2 <- complete(imp, action = 2, include = FALSE)
x3 <- complete(imp, action = 3, include = FALSE)
x4 <- complete(imp, action = 4, include = FALSE)
x5 <- complete(imp, action = 5, include = FALSE)

## Apply the following method for each imputed set 

form <- iris$Sepal.Width # target column
n <- nrow(x1)  # since all data sample are the same length
prop <- n%/%fold
set.seed(7)
newseq <- rank(runif(n))
k <- as.factor((newseq - 1)%/%prop + 1)
CVfolds <- 10


CVrepeats <- 3
  indexPreds <- createMultiFolds(x1[k != i,]$Sepal.Width, CVfolds, CVrepeats)
  ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = CVrepeats,number = CVfolds, returnResamp = "all", savePredictions = "all", index = indexPreds)




fit1 <- train(Sepal.Width ~., data = x1[k !=i, ],method='svmLinear2',trControl = ctrl)
fit2 <- train(Sepal.Width ~., data = x2[k != i, ],method='svmLinear2',trControl = ctrl)
fit3 <- train(Sepal.Width ~., data = x3[k != i, ],method='svmLinear2',trControl = ctrl)
fit4 <- train(Sepal.Width ~., data = x4[k != i, ],method='svmLinear2',trControl = ctrl)
fit5 <- train(Sepal.Width ~., data = x5[k != i, ],method='svmLinear2',trControl = ctrl)




#combine the created model to a list
      svm.fit <- list(svmLinear1 = fit1, svmLinear2 = fit2, svmLinear3 = fit3, svmLinear4 = fit4, svmLinear5 = fit5)

  # convert the list to cartlist
  class(svm.fit) <- "caretList" 

  #create the ensemble where the error occur.
  svm.all <- caretEnsemble(svm.fit,method='svmLinear2')
```

Comment: i think you forgot to specify iris here in `form <- Sepal.Width`.

Comment: Thank you for spotting this, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simplify your example. Too many moving parts and the loop is not needed for getting the error. One of the internal caretEnsemble controls is throwing this error, but the message is not well defined.

That being said, 
caretList needs to have a specified `trainControl` object which you use with each train model. Otherwise the resampling will be different for each model and you will get the error:

> "Component models do not have the same re-sampling strategies"

Next issue is that you are using different datasets with each train object. CaretEnsemble is meant to be used with the same training dataset. Your x1 to x5 are all different even though they have the same basis. This will lead to the error:

> "Observed values for each component model are not the same.  Please
>   re-train the models with the same Y variable"

Last, if you want to build a `model.list` from separately trained models just use `c(model1, model2)`. see documentation `c.train`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I really appreciate it and I have simplify the code as suggested. Can you please provide me with an example of building a model.list from separately trained models? and is that mean I can't build caretEnsemble with models associated with different training data-sets.?